# How `parity-bridges-common` is intended to be used for development?

Tags: polkadot, xcm, build, bridge

So there is a repo [parity-bridges-common](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common) that contains "Useful Bridge Building Tools" and is currently under development.

This repo uses XCMv3 branches of polkadot and substrate (which is not released to master yet), however we need to work with main versions of `Substrate/Polkadot` (for example, with latest polkadot v0.9.26). What would be the best way to organise it (i.e. how to use these templates/examples in more recent versions)?

In [parity-bridges-common's Cargo.toml](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/16aaeb9f9d80c5437001f4739b7f8a338287bf4b/Cargo.toml#L17) and in some [old PR](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/pull/1378) it is written that the intention is to move to the main versions later when the 3rd XCM version will be released. So one way is to work with this branch as well. However, it would require to (kind of) rollback to older version of substrate (since the XCM branch diverged from main ones about 3 months ago). Furthermore, I'm worried that latter migration to newer substrate version (on XCM v3 release) may turn out labour intensive.

Is there any better way to use these bridge tools for development or such overhead is unavoidable?